# Как увеличить изображение сгенерированное в PHP по клику

Tags: javascript, php

PHP генерирует много изображений, все нормально отображаются. Попробовал по классу через JS onclick менять стиль, но не реагирует на нажатие  - в консоли нету ошибок.

```
<?php
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $name = $row['code'];
     $start_op = $row['start_time_operation'];
     $end_op = $row['end_time_operation'];
     $type = $row['type'];
     $map = $row['map'];

     echo "<li>$id - $name - $start_op - $end_op - $type - <img src='images/$map' style='height:20px;' class='line-img'>-$map</li>";
  }
?>
```

JS

```
 var zoom = false;                                          
 document.getElementsByClassName('line-img').onclick = function() {
    if (zoom == false) {
       zoom = true;
       document.getElementsByClassName('line-img').style.position = "absolute";
       document.getElementsByClassName('line-img').style.height = "550px";
    }
    if (zoom == true) {
       zoom = false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: а где javascript?

Comment: вот добавил   )))

Answer (score 0):

проблема в том что  document.getElementsByClassName('line-img') возвращает не элемент  а NodeList, тебе что бы навесить слушатель нужно прогонять через цикл это все.

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.line-img')).forEach(item =>
    item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if (zoom == false) {
            zoom = true
            event.target.style.position = 'absolute'
            event.target.style.height = '550px'
        }
        if (zoom == true) {
            zoom = false
        }
    })
```

и getElementsByClassName  работает медленнее чем document.querySelectorAll  как ни странно